# Can I read the C++ 2011 FDIS anywhere?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, iso

I probably can't, but I really would like to. Can I read the C++ 2011 FDIS anywhere?

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) to the penultimate draft from Feb 2011. The differences between this and the FDIS are minor and mostly only relevant to language lawyers.

Comment: Good thing I got that N3290 version downloaded, before it got locked away :)

Answer (score 20):

Post-C++11, Stefanus Du Toit (the new editor for the C++ standardization committee) is maintaining the standard draft on github. The [github page](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) states:

> These are the sources used to generate drafts of the C++ standard.
>   These sources should not be considered an ISO publication, nor should
>   documents generated from them unless officially adopted by the C++
>   working group (ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21).

You can grab the LaTeX sources using

```
git clone https://github.com/cplusplus/draft.git
```

then build a PDF with

```
make document
```

The original check-in to this repository had (essentially) the same content as the C++11 standard as published by ISO; the changes since then have (so far) been purely editorial fixes.

It is worth noting that the [wiki for the draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/wiki) says:

> This repository *does not* contain the official C++ standard.

In particular, changes made in that repository should not be considered official parts of the C++ language until they are ratified by ISO.

**Update:** A [copy of the published standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) with only minor editorial changes was included in the [pre-Kona mailing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/) as N3337.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [download link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n3290.pdf) to the pdf [N3290]

Comment: Why does it require authorization?

Comment: @cpx: Its no longer free it seems.

Comment: @acidzombie - A guess is that the final standard will look almost exactly like the FDIS. It would be hard to sell the book if you give away the manuscript for free.

Comment: @Bo: Well, theres a difference between a hardcopy and a non hardcopy but AFAIK all the standards are online

Comment: @acidzombie24: Nope. The ISO standards have always cost money, unfortunately. You can find late drafts of everything but the final standard can be expensive. (both C and C++ suffer from this)

Comment: @acidzombie - They might be online, but not all are free. ISO and ANSI sell standards in PDF form as well as hardcopies.

Comment: Wow, I downloaded this thing just yesterday, for free... like it had been since it was put online, until now I guess. Dang, everyone else seems out of luck then

Comment: @BoPersson: "It would be hard to sell the book if you give away the manuscript for free." However, more and more authors are doing exactly that.

Comment: Herb Sutter had this to say about the password protection (http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/#comment-3079): "All C++ committee documents are public, except for membership lists and the final text of the standard. ISO rules, sorry — I did ask permission to leave the draft unprotected, but ISO prohibits sharing the final text of FCD and FDIS documents, so ISO said no because that draft is technically identical to the FDIS and differs from the final FDIS text by only the cover page."

Comment: @Michael Herb Sutter [also had some things to say] (http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/#comment-2817) about various ways to buy the standard and some respondents also suggested alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Can you download [N3291](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n3291.pdf)?  This will have the same text except that changes from the previous working draft [N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) are highlighted.

**Update:**

Try downloading the entire post-Madrid mailing either in [zip format](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/mailings/papers/2011/2011-04-post-Madrid.zip) or in [tar format](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/mailings/papers/2011/2011-04.tar.gz).  If the mailing don't require authorization, then you're in luck. They do contain N3290.

**Update 2:**

I've learned that making these documents protected was requested of the website maintainer in order to stay aligned with ISO JTC 1 rules.

Comment: "Authorization required." However, if I download http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3291.pdf , I get a file called n3281.pdf, which is just a random paper and not a complete draft. Odd.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've updated my answer with another possibility.  I have authorization and so it is difficult for me to tell when it is needed.