# =default ignores access specifier?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, defaulted-functions

I found it quite odd that the following program still compiled fine despite the default constructor being `private` (4.8.1 g++):

```
 class A{
 private:
     A() = default;
     A(const A&) = default;
 };

 int main(){

     A a;

 }
```

Actually from 8.4.2[2] of the standard (N3242)

> An explicitly-defaulted function may be declared constexpr only if it would have been implicitly declared as constexpr. If it is explicitly defaulted on its first declaration,
>
> — it shall be public,
>
> ..........

What exactly is the purpose for the default specifier to ignore the access specification? I feel like that could cause an interface issue unwarranted by the class designer that didn't want users to create default values but needed the default constructor in the implementation. I thought that maybe it's because the default constructor is normally `public` and so the `default` aims to replicate it - but that doesn't answer why `=default` on the copy constructor doesn't ignore the `private` specification.

```
 class A{
 private:
     A() = default;
     A(const A&) = default;
 };

 int main(){

     A a;
     A b(a); //error: constexpr A::A(const A&) is private

 }
```

Actually I can't see from the standard where it mentions that explicitly-defaulted `copy/move` constructors/assignments aren't made `public`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a gcc bug. [Bug 57913](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57913) contains an example almost identical to yours. [Bug 56429](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56429) contains links to several related bug reports, of which [bug 54812](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54812) has been fixed in gcc 4.9, which indeed rejects your code.

```
error: 'constexpr A::A()' is private
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3bac6d22382bff2)

Comment: Alrighty, thanks. I guess I misunderstood that quote from the standard. It was being completely specific to the context of `constexpr` declared functions.

Comment: @Silversonic Which version of the standard are you quoting? I can't find the *it shall be public* part in either N3337 or N4296

Comment: I was looking at N3242. I thought that was the best one to look at if I was working with C++11? Should I swap to N3337?

Comment: @Silversonic N3337 is the first draft published after the ISO C++11 standard version (which is not free). Richard Smith says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8323351/241631) that it only contains minor editorial differences from the published standard, so I'd switch to that rather than use a version from before publication.

Comment: @Silversonic [Here's](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1135) the issue that brought about the change in wording from what you're quoting